# DC/OS private registry with authentication fails

Tags: azure, docker-registry, mesosphere, registrykey, dcos

I got a running DC/OS cluster on Azure and i'm trying to configure it to use private registry credentials. 
I'm running Azure Private Registry with admin. I can log in and use the images.

I followed the guide provided by DC/OS but it recommends saving it on the nodes themselves. I want to use Azure File Storage instead.

I saved the config.json file to auth to the loginserver on a blob and provide the URI with deployment configuration.

config.json:

```
auths:  
  stageon.azurecr.io:   
     auth   "..."
```

Now the configuration just keeps running without any output so I assume it's hanging on pulling the image.

I am providing the direct link URL to the file and when I access it through webbrowser it returns the JSON.

Did anyone do something similar before I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31075733/how-should-a-dockercfg-file-be-hosted-in-a-mesosphere-on-aws-setup-so-that-only/31180422#31180422)  for amazon before but I can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a customization to acs-engine a few times to push registry credentials to the agent nodes.

This approach makes sure that the credentials will be present even when you add nodes later on.

The code is here: https://github.com/xtophs/acs-engine-1/tree/xtoph-registry. Example cluster API model is at: https://github.com/xtophs/acs-engine-1/blob/xtoph-registry/examples/privateregistry/dcos1.8.4.json